# Drag and drop API not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm working on a group project for my software engineering course. To make a long story short I'm trying to use the drag and drop HTML API, but I'm not having any luck. Below is the html for the page I'm trying to implement the drag and drop on. There are multiple files within the project as this is a website, if there isn't enough information I will upload the other files at the request. In the HTML file below all I'm trying to do is drop `hello` `<p>` into the `div1` `<div>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Fundamentals of SE (Scratchat)</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- jQuery cdn -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script>
            function openNav() {
                document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
                document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
            }

            function closeNav() {
                document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
                document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
            }
            function allowDrop(ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
            }

            function drag(ev) {
                ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
            }

            function drop(ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
                ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="aboutus.html">About us</a>
            <a href="features.html">Features</a>
            <a href="#">Build</a>
            <a href="tutorial.html">Tutorial</a>
            <a href="https://scratch.mit.edu/about">About Scratch</a>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
            <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer; color: #white" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
        </div>

        <div class="div1" style="height: 100px; width: 100%; border: solid 2px black" draggable="true" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

        </div>

<!--
        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                <div id="scratchWindow" style="padding-top: 200px; padding-bottom: 200px;">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
-->

        <div class="question" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
            <p>
                Hello
<!--            
                <label>What Question Do You Want Your Bot To Ask?</label><br>
                <textarea
                    id = "Question"
                    rows = 3
                    cols = 20>Your Question Here</textarea>
-->
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

HERE IS THE CSS FILE USED GLOBALLY ACROSS THE WEBSITE:

```
.jumbotron {
    background-image: url("../res/robot-customer-service.png");
    background-position: 0% 25%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    margin-top: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: white;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #1974fc;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #36bac3;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

body {

    background: url("https://cdn0.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2015/04/colortheory.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for error reports? If not I suggest you look and include them into your question if you have any.

Comment: @NewToJS Not I didn't, but there was an error that returns `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at drop (scratchat.html:30)
    at HTMLDivElement.ondrop (scratchat.html:50)`

Comment: Maybe this will help you [**Developer Mozilla DataTransfer/getData API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/getData)

Comment: @NewToJS Correct me if I'm wrong, but I need to use a function for `Node` instead of `document`? If that is the case is there a similar function for `Node` that corresponds to `document.getElementById()`? Would `element.getElementsByClassName()` be what I'm looking for?

Comment: Using `getElementsByClassName()` will return a group of elements, a node list so you will have to select the one you want to target. Also your draggable div and the one use to get the drop don't have `ID's` so you are trying to target an element with no ID at this point `ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));` Unless I am reading it wrong. I would recommend you `console.log();` things to ensure you are targeting and the variables contain/return the correct data.

Comment: @user2172993 If you feel the answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the green check mark

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are grabbing the whole `div` instead of just the `text`.

Give your paragraph - `<p>` element an `id` and add your `draggable` & `ondragstart` attributes to it.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```html
<div class="div1" style="height: 100px; width: 100%; border: solid 2px black" draggable="true" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>
<div class="question">
  <p id="hello" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    Hello
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention the `ID` you have added to the paragraph element.... `id="hello"` otherwise just placing the `draggable` and `ondragstart` attributes to the paragraph won't work without the `id` adding too.

Comment: No problem :) It can avoid further confusion and it's a simple thing to forget.

Comment: @NewToJS Thank you so much for the help, I was pretty stumped. I don't have much experience with CSS or HTML so I'm just kinda learning on the "job"

Comment: @user2172993 You are very welcome and we all have to start somewhere. This is **Kemotoe**'s answer and provided the source code so the credit should be to Kemotoe.